# Is it good practice to ignore .classpath and .project (or .iml) when pushing to a repository?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, intellij-idea, gitignore

I am working on a final Java project for the semester with a group of other students, and we want to use a git repository to combine our efforts.

As there is no standard which IDE is used, we have .iml as well as .project and .classpath in our repository. It seems to me that this increases the importability of the project when cloning onto a new machine, but I'm sure there has to be some kind of conflict just waiting to happen.

What's the best practice here? Ignore .iml and .classpath/.project or commit them?

Comment: even though I don't consider this a question for SO, I'll answer anyway: I always ignore it, because I have no intent on deciding for someone else who might later work on the same code what IDE they could/should use. It has nothing to do with the project, rather with the IDE you've chosen to use. If you add it, you set what IDE to use, and possibly even more 'local config', like in what folder the project should be

Comment: Generally you want to ignore any local specific to your environment configuration. It does not make sense to push these in the repo, as all people have different environments and setup on their machines. Take a look at the files you describe - they contain class paths and so on which are specific to your environment only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest ignore the .iml and .settings and everything related to code editors or compilers. Have the setting as ambigious as possible so people can edit it in whichever format they want in whatever IDE they want.

With eclipse .settings for example, if the path differs, there will be unexpected side effects, messages of projects not found etc.. because eclipse tends to hardcode the path to the project. So /users/john/desktop/project/ won't run for /users/fred/desktop/project.

And it's not that much of an effort to set up an IDE to work with it.
Include in your project a quick setup manual for the most commonly used editors as a quick reference sheet.

If you use gradle you can take a look at how minecraft forge does it.
It has setup scripts for eclipse and for idea, so all the proper libraries are loaded and the runtimes are configured for the relevant IDE's